# how can i get four last scores of each course in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

my database have four tables: `student`, `course`, `stu_course`, `score`.

columns for **course** table: **id, name**

columns for **student** table: **id, firs_name, last_name, username, password**

columns for **stu_course** table: **id, stu_id, course_id**
(stu_id and cours_id are foreign keys)

columns fir **score** table: **id, stu_cours_id, score, date**
(stu_cours_id is forein ksy)

My question is how can i get four last scores of each course in score table?
here is what i currently have:

```
SELECT s.first_name
     , c.name
     , sc.id
     , k.score
     , k.date
     ,  
  FROM student s
  JOIN stu_course sc
    ON sc.stu_id = s.id
  JOIN course c
    ON c.id = sc.course_id
  JOIN score k
    ON k.stu_course_id = sc.id
```

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Version of MySQL?

Comment: Version of MySQL: 10.1.37-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0 (Maria DB >= 10.2), you could use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank the scores of each course by descending date. Then, just filter out records with a rank higher than 4:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT student.first_name, course.name, stu_course.id, score.score, score.date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY course.id ORDER BY score.date DESC) rn
    FROM `student`
    INNER JOIN stu_course ON stu_course.stu_id = student.id
    INNER JOIN course ON course.id = stu_course.course_id
    INNER JOIN score ON score.stu_course_id=stu_course.id
) x WHERE rn <= 4
```

---

In earlier versions of MySQL/MariaDB, a solution would be to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT 
    s.first_name, 
    c.name, 
    sc.id, 
    k.score, 
    k.date 
FROM student s 
JOIN stu_course sc ON sc.stu_id = s.id 
JOIN course c ON c.id = sc.course_id 
JOIN score k 
    ON k.stu_course_id = sc.id 
    AND (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM score k1 WHERE k1.stu_course_id = k.stu_course_id AND k1.date > k.date
    ) <= 3
```

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: @y.mohammad65: welcome! Have you been able to test the query against your database?

Comment: this only returns 4 last rows from whole result. i want results which contains 4 last rows of each course

Comment: @y.mohammad65: yes, that what the `PARTITION BY course.id` clause does... Can you can remove the `WHERE` clause, and make sure that you have more than one distinct `course.id` in your data ?

Comment: i think ROW_NUMBER() not work

Comment: this line return error:   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY course.id ORDER BY score.date DESC) rn

Comment: @y.mohammad65: which version of MySQL are you using? I mentionned that `ROW_NUMBER()` is available since version 8.0...

Comment: what are rn and x?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10

Comment: @y.mohammad65: `x` is an alias for the subquery (it's important in SQL), and `rn` is the row number that was computed in the subquery. Can you please run `SELECT @@VERSION;` and let me know what it returns?

Comment: @y.mohammad65: [window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/) (such as `ROW_NUMBER()`) are available starting MariaDB 10.2, so your version does not support them...

Comment: I do not know the meaning of the rn and x in your sql statement

Comment: is there no other solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Can you try this query: `SELECT s.first_name, c.name, sc.id, k.score, k.date
FROM student s
JOIN stu_course sc 
    ON sc.stu_id = s.id
JOIN course c 
    ON c.id = sc.course_id
JOIN score k
    ON k.stu_course_id = sc.id
 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM score k1 WHERE k1.course_id = k.course_id AND k1.date > k.date) <= 3`

Comment: @y.mohammad65: is the new query working for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not working

Comment: your last code return this error: Unknown column 'k1.course_id' in 'where clause' - score table dose not have course_id column

Comment: @y.mohammad65: sorry - should be ... WHERE k1.stu_course_id = k.stu_course_id

Comment: it works right. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `SELECT s.first_name, c.name, sc.id, k.score, k.date FROM student s 
JOIN stu_course sc ON sc.stu_id = s.id 
JOIN course c ON c.id = sc.course_id 
JOIN score k ON k.stu_course_id = sc.id AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM score k1 
    WHERE k1.stu_course_id = k.stu_course_id AND k1.date > k.date) <= 3`

Comment: yesterday I checked for a limited amount of data and worked fine
but now that the number of data has increased, it does not work properly

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ORDER BY statement to sort your list (use order by desc to sort descending) then use LIMIT x to just show the first x results.

Effectively if you use ORDER BY  DESC LIMIT x you'll see the bottom x results when sorted by your chosen column

Comment: This doesn't return the last 4 for each course, it only returns the last four from _any_ course.